# Adding list to dictionary in loop adds last list only

Tags: python, python-3.x

When finished adding items to `current_page` list it should add the list to `page_dic` dictionary then delete it. It builds the lists correctly but only seems to add the last one.

**Code:**

```
# Example Item List
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]


# Build Page Dictionary
page_dic = {}
page_amount = 2

page_count = 1
current_page = []

print(f'All Items: {items}')
for item in items:
    if len(current_page) == page_amount:
        print(f'To Add: {current_page}')
        page_dic[f'page_{page_count}'] = current_page
        page_count += 1

        del current_page[:]

        current_page.append(item)
    else:
        current_page.append(item )

print(f'To Add: {current_page}')
page_dic[f'page_{page_count}'] = current_page

print(f'Result: {page_dic}')
```

**Expected Result:** `{'page_1': ['a', 'b'], 'page_2': ['c', 'd'], 'page_3': ['e']}`

**Result:** `{'page_1': ['e'], 'page_2': ['e'], 'page_3': ['e']}`

Comment: Yes because you only ever add the same `list` object: `page_dic[f'page_{page_count}'] = current_page` in other words, there is only ever one list.

Comment: use ````current_page=[]````  instead of ````del current_page[:]```` to create a new list

Comment: Thank you @NebiyouTen that works. I don't understand why it would make a difference tho.

Comment: You didn't create a new list. You were just deleting the elements of the same list and updating them. So all the values in your dictionary were the same ````current_page```` object.